# Requested site does not appear to have claims enabled or the Login Url has not been set

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, claims-based-auth

i am currently getting information from my company's sharepoint page and display it on my asp.net project. I am using *ClaimClientContext* for authentication, and of course in my local host it is working fine.

However, when I publish the site and place it on my server the following error occurred: *The requested site does not appear to have claims enabled or the Login Url has not been set.*

The error is pointing to the Url which i have stated in my code:

```
 Using ctx As ClientContext = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext("https://abc.sharepoint.com/team/Wiki/")
```

Any idea on how I can overcome this error? Do let me know if more information is needed, and i will gladly provide. Thank you.